# Getting an object from a table row in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, react-table, react-button

I'm a beginner working on a simple CRUD, and all I want to do is get the user from the selected row. If you look below:

```
      {/* ANCHOR - TABLE ROWS */}
      {admins.map((user, index) => (
          <tbody key={index}>

            <tr>
              <td style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{user._id}</td>
              <td>{shortenStr(user.username)}</td>
              <td>{shortenStr(user.firstName)}</td>
              <td>{shortenStr(user.lastName)}</td>
              <td>{shortenStr(user.dob)}</td>
              <td>

                <div className="button-div">
                  <button id="updateUser" 
                  className="button-update-admin" 
                  onClick={handleClick && console.log(user.firstName)}>
                  </button>
                </div>

              </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
      ))}
```

Console.log gives me the first names of every user in the table, such as:

```
John
Steve
Frank
```

Ideally I would like to pass the user Data into my handle click function so that I can create a context, perhaps. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what does `handleClick` do?

Comment: `onClick={handleClick(user.firstName)}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change -

```
onClick={handleClick && console.log(user.firstName)}>
```

To

```
onClick={() => {
  console.log(user.firstName)
}}
```

Or if you want to have a separate `onClick` function with the `event` data -

```
function handleClick(event, user) {
    console.log(user.firstName);
}
...
onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, user)}
```

[image: Edit purple-tdd-ly0263]

Comment: How do I pass a parameter into an onClick function if I have an event, such as: const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent, firstName: string) => {}. In other words how do I pass the event as an argument? For example: onClick={handleClick(event, user.firstName)} this doesnt work, and removing the event gives me an error: Expected 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: You can pass the event as `onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, user)}`. I have updated the answer & codesandbox.